# Check if an array contains an object with a certain property value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

If I have something like

```
[Object(id:03235252, name:"streetAddress"), Object(id:32624666, name:"zipCode")...]
```

How can I **remove** an object from that array that has **name set to** "zipCode"?

Comment: should be correctly written:
[{id: 03235252, name: "streetAddress"}, {id: 32624666, name: "zipCode"}]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you need to modify the existing Array, you should use `splice()`.

```
for (var i = array.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
    if (array[i].name === "zipCode")
        array.splice(i, 1);
}
```

Notice that I'm looping in reverse. This is in order to deal with the fact that when you do a `.splice(i, 1)`, the array will be reindexed.

If we did a forward loop, we would also need to adjust `i` whenever we do a `.splice()` in order to avoid skipping an index.

Answer (score 9):

```
arr = arr.filter(function (item) {
  return (item.name !== 'zipCode');
});
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that it [doesn't work in IE 8](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/) so you might have to [shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Compatibility) it.

Comment: Should be noted that this doesn't remove the object from the Array. It builds a new Array and replaces the old one, which could be an issue if there are multiple references to the same Array.

Answer (score 3):

### Updated suggestion

Updated this answer due to doing prototypes on arrays are bad prac so to get people who use the suggestion to write better code here is a better option:

```
const myArr = [
  {
    name: "lars",
    age: 25
  }, {
    name: "hugo",
    age: 28
  }, {
    name: "bent",
    age: 24
  }, {
    name: "jimmy",
    age: 22
  }
];

const findAndRemove = (array, prop, value) => {
  return array.filter((item) => item[prop] !== value);
}

const newArr = findAndRemove(myArr, 'name', 'jimmy')

console.log(newArr)

// Could also be simply written like this:
const otherArr = myArr.filter(item => item.name !== 'jimmy')
```

New code can be found and tested **[here](https://codepen.io/sp90/pen/jOrNzwE?editors=0010)**

### Old suggestion

<strike>This can also be done with a prototype on the array</strike>

```
Array.prototype.containsByProp = function(propName, value){
      for (var i = this.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        var propObj = this[i];
          if(propObj[propName] === value) {
            return true;
        }
      }
    return false;
} 

var myArr = [
  {
    name: "lars",
    age: 25
  }, {
    name: "hugo",
    age: 28
  }, {
    name: "bent",
    age: 24
  }, {
    name: "jimmy",
    age: 22
  }
];

console.log(myArr.containsByProp("name", "brent")); // Returns false
console.log(myArr.containsByProp("name", "bent")); // Returns true
```

Code can also be found and tested **[here](http://codepen.io/sp90/pen/rOjoEm)**

Answer (score 2):

```
var i = array.length;
while(i-- > 0) {
    if (array[i].name === "zipCode")
        array.splice(i, 1);
}
```

- Loop through the array backwards (so you won't have to skip indexes when splicing)
- Check each item's name if it's "zipCode"

  - If it is, splice it off using `yourArray.splice(index,1)`;

Then either:

- continue if there is a possibility of having more than one name having the value "zipCode"
- break the loop

Answer (score 0):

This may be a **detailed and easy** solution.

```
//plain array
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var check = arr.includes('a');
console.log(check); //returns true
if (check)
{
   // value exists in array
   //write some codes
}

// array with objects
var arr = [
      {x:'a', y:'b'},
      {x:'p', y:'q'}
  ];

// if you want to check if x:'p' exists in arr
var check = arr.filter(function (elm){
    if (elm.x == 'p')
    {
       return elm; // returns length = 1 (object exists in array)
    }
});

// or y:'q' exists in arr
var check = arr.filter(function (elm){
    if (elm.y == 'q')
    {
       return elm; // returns length = 1 (object exists in array)
    }
});

// if you want to check, if the entire object {x:'p', y:'q'} exists in arr
var check = arr.filter(function (elm){
    if (elm.x == 'p' && elm.y == 'q')
    {
       return elm; // returns length = 1 (object exists in array)
    }
});

// in all cases
console.log(check.length); // returns 1

if (check.length > 0)
{
   // returns true
   // object exists in array
   //write some codes
}
```